# how to add update entity in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

work environment: php + mysql

I want to add an entity from DAO layer to database with the following use case:

- Create row in database if it doesn't exist, otherwise, update the record in database.

This needs to be done on a big scale, around 100 million users.

A) In DAO; fetch from database to see if the entity exists. If not, create it in database. If it exists, update the record accordingly.

B) Approach A can be delegated to a procedure in database ? Instead of going back and forth between DAO and DB (which I think is expensive), can we just call a procedure in mysql and let it do the work ?

Also, is there a better way to deal with this situation ?

Scenario:

DB tables

```
User:
- uid
- name

Post
- pid
- details
- url

UserPosts
- uid
- pid
```

A user can make many posts. At DAO, I have a user with a list object. I need to add/update the user to database.

Comment: what about try an update if that fails insert

Comment: same thing: two calls to db per request

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/a/2848937/1114171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few answers I dug up which looks like what you want, basically putting the onus on the db to decide whether to insert or update

- for [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2848937/1114171)
- for [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109198/1114171)
- for [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589730/1114171)

Answer (score 0):

```
//first, check if it exists in database using a SELECT statement   
$sqlCheck = mysql_query("") or die("check");

//determine the row count
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlCheck);

if ($rowCount == 0) { //if it returns 0 rows, then execute using INSERT statement
     $sqlInsert = mysql_query("") or die(mysql_error());    
}
else { // if there's a record, update the database
     $sqlUpdate = mysql_query("") or die("update"); 
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: You described the case A I mentioned. My point here, it takes two calls to database per request which would be a bad idea when we scale the same operation to million of requests. Thoughts ?